# load data from sqlite is working fine in one fragment while not working in second fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I have asynctask in mainActivity and saving that data into sqlite.But when I am loading that data in viewpager frags,its working fine in one while nothing is happening in second fragment.Can someone help me?

```
public class CurrentContests extends Fragment {

        private String TAG = CurrentContests.class.getSimpleName();

        RecyclerView rv;
        ProgressDialog pdialog;
        public DataAdapter adapter;
        protected static ArrayList<DataModel> data;
        private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
        static View v;
        private static final String SELECT_SQL = "SELECT * FROM ankit";
        public SQLiteDatabase db;
        private Cursor c;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.currentcontests_layout, container, false);
            data = new ArrayList<>();
            rv = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.tab1_recycler_view);
            rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            rv.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            adapter = new DataAdapter(data);
            rv.setAdapter(adapter);
           /* new GetContacts().execute();*/
            openDatabase();


            c = db.rawQuery(SELECT_SQL, null);
            //c.moveToFirst();
            //showRecords();
            db.beginTransaction();
            shownow();
            return v;
        }

        protected void openDatabase() {
            db =getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("ankitDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);//openOrCreateDatabase("ankitDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        }
        private void shownow(){
            //if the cursor isnt null we will essentially iterate over rows and then columns
            //to form a table of data as per database.
            if (c != null) {

                //more to the first row
                c.moveToFirst();
                Log.e("current", "shownow");
                //iterate over rows
                for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {

                    String site = c.getString(1);
                    String name = c.getString(2);
                    String begin_date = c.getString(3);
                    String begin_time=c.getString(4);
                    String end_date=c.getString(5);
                    String end_time=c.getString(6);
                    String type=c.getString(7);
                    //String type=c.getString(8);

                        DataModel dm = new DataModel(site, name, begin_date, begin_time, end_date, end_time);//,i+1,R.drawable.codechef);
                        data.add(dm);


                    //move to the next row
                    c.moveToNext();
                }
                //close the cursor
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
               db.endTransaction();
                c.close();
                db.close();
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

This is my **Second Fragment**

```
public class SecondContent extends Fragment {

        private String TAG = UpcommingContests.class.getSimpleName();
        RecyclerView rv;
        ProgressDialog pdialog;
        public DataAdapter adapter;
        protected static ArrayList<DataModel> data;
        private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
        static View v;

        private static final String SELECT_SQL = "SELECT * FROM ankit";

        public SQLiteDatabase dbup;

        private Cursor cup;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.upcomingcontests_layout, container, false);
            data = new ArrayList<>();
            rv = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.rv_tab2);
            rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            rv.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            adapter = new DataAdapter(data);
            rv.setAdapter(adapter);
           /* new GetContacts().execute();*/
            openDatabase();
            cup = dbup.rawQuery(SELECT_SQL, null);
            //c.moveToFirst();
            //showRecords();
            shownow();
            return v;
        }
        protected void openDatabase() {
            dbup =getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("ankitDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);//openOrCreateDatabase("ankitDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        }
        private void shownow(){
            //if the cursor isnt null we will essentially iterate over rows and then columns
            //to form a table of data as per database.
            if (cup != null) {
                //more to the first row
                cup.moveToFirst();
                Log.e("upcoming","shownow");
                //iterate over rows
                for (int i = 0; i < cup.getCount(); i++) {
                    String site = cup.getString(1);
                    String name = cup.getString(2);
                    String begin_date = cup.getString(3);
                    String begin_time=cup.getString(4);
                    String end_date=cup.getString(5);
                    String end_time=cup.getString(6);
                    String type=cup.getString(7);
                    //String type=c.getString(8);
                    Log.e("upcoming",site+"");
                        DataModel dm = new DataModel(site, name, begin_date, begin_time, end_date, end_time);//,i+1,R.drawable.codechef);
                        data.add(dm);
                    //move to the next row
                    cup.moveToNext();
                }
                //close the cursor
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                cup.close();
                dbup.close();

            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: please  help me @Raunak

Comment: Can you post your code of second fragment?

Comment: please first check that your cursor is empty or not ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be in database transactions management. When transaction is started it blocks access to the database from any other places until it is ended.

In your case, you start transaction in `onCreateView()` and finish it only if cursor wasn't null. This means that in case when your cursor is null the database will stay blocked.

Prefer to use database transactions in try-finally blocks to prevent such behaviour:

```
    db.beginTransaction();
try {
    // do your work
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch {
    //Error between database transaction. Or skip catch if not necessary 
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```